# Attaching something to a global in js if there is no global

Tags: browserify, browserify-shim

I'm using threejs and browserify and everything works fine so far, as threejs has browserify support I can just require threejs.

But what do I do, when I want to use something like this script 
http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/FirstPersonControls.js

This script requires a global `THREE` variable to be present so that it can attach itself to it. But if I do

```
var three = require('../three.min.js');
```

there is no global `THREE`. I could do

```
THREE = require('../three.min.js');
```

but thats not nice. I tried to find a solution using browserify-shim but was unsuccessful. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it with THREE, but the following works for me with jQuery, lodash, and moment:

this is placed inside your app.js file:

```
  // Properly designed libraries that enable node compatibility.
  var $ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
  var _ = window._ = require("lodash");
  var moment = window.moment = require("moment");
```